# Authenticating user with iOS FacebookSDK logs user out

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the FB iOS SDK to get the user's credentials and access token and save them. With the previous version I managed to properly do this, but my solution broke with the upgrade to iOS 6, so I downloaded the new version from Github, and compiled and added the framework to my project according to the instructions.

I properly authenticate my user with FB, but when the browser (the modal view controller presented for auth) is dismissed my user reverts to the initial view of my app instead of the view that the process was launched from.

Right now I have code in my app delegate and my `SocialNetworksViewController` to do this.

In `AppDelegate`:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
} 

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
   presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
  switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen: {
      [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
      break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
      // Once the user has logged in, we want them to
      // be looking at the root view.

      [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
                                                      object:session];

  if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
  }
}

- (void)openSessionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
  NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"email", @"user_birthday", nil];
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                 allowLoginUI:YES
                            completionHandler:
   ^(FBSession *session,
     FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session presentingViewController:viewController state:state error:error];
   }];
}
```

In `SocialNetworksViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)connectToFacebook:(UIButton *)sender {
  if (!self.facebookConnected) {
    AppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate> *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate openSessionFromViewController:self];
  }
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

  NSLog(@"%@", FBSession.activeSession.accessToken);
}

- (void)facebookLoginFailed {
}
```

This is in `viewDidLoad` as well:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(sessionStateChanged:)
                                               name:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
                                             object:nil];
```

In the `sessionStateChanged` method, the `NSLog` outputs and then I get send to my initial view.

Comment: This `SocialNetworksViewController *snvc = [[[[(UITabBarController *)[[[self window] rootViewController] modalViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:4] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
` looks so phreakin horrible. SHAME!

Comment: It is absolutely horrible, I know, but I don't know of a better way to get to the view controller that calls the method. I find the whole way the Facebook SDK works terrible. Any suggestion to improve that is welcome.

Comment: Actually just thought of a way with the new way this SDK works, will update the code shortly. At least that I can fix.